# Updating sum in a column in first table with data from other table

Tags: sql, db2

I have table1 as below:

```
Col1    Bal
-------------------
 1       0
 2       0
 3       0
 4       0
```

Col1 is the key here.

I have table2 as below:

```
Col1    Bal    Date
---------------------
 1       5      x
 1       10     y
 1       7      z
 3       8      p
 3       9      m
```

Col1 is the join column in both tables.

I want to update bal in first table with sum of bal in 2nd table.

What would be the sql statement for this:

```
update table1 a set a.bal=(select sum(b.bal) from table2) where
```

and I am lost!

After update, table1 should be:

```
Col1    Bal
-------------------
 1       22
 2       0
 3       17
 4       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0001022.htm), it looks like you can use table aliases in DB2:

```
update  table1 a 
set     bal = coalesce(
        (
        select  sum(b.bal) 
        from    table2 as b
        where   a.col1 = b.col1
        ), 0)
```

Comment: Here issue is, initially all balances were 0, but through your query, the unmatching col1 are now becoming null. If possible, I want to avoid it. So instead of Bal for 2 and 4 being null.. I want them as 0

Comment: You could use `coalesce` for that, added to answer